# Warning with sending emails from Thunderbird to Postfix using its own CA

Tags: postfix, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority, thunderbird

I'm asking for help because I simply don't have the strength anymore, I've spent a lot of time and I'm still left with an unsolved puzzle.
My problem: I keep getting "Wrong Site" warnings when sending email.
I would like it to be done cleanly without such frills. Here is a description of what I did and what the message that haunts me looks like.

Description of the steps I took:
I created my own CA following these instructions:
`https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/application-gateway/self-signed-certificates`

I added the server certificate to Postfix:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/fabrikam.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/fabrikam.key
```

I added my CA to Thunderbird:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsYXb.png)

And unfortunately, despite this, when I try to send an email, I still receive the following warning:

```
This site attempts to identify itself with invalid information.

Wrong Site
The certificate belongs to a different site, which could mean that someone is trying ti impersonate this site.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa3px.png)

In the Postfix logs I have this:

```
SSL3 alert read:fatal:bad certificate
SSL_accept:error in error
SSL_accept error from unknown[10.0.200.202]: -1
warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000412:SSL routines::ssl
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccazb.png)

After running the certificate verification command (openssl x509 -in fabrikam.crt -text -noout) I have the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Bf3.png)

Please help. If you need any information, write and I will add it.

Comment: Looks like you added the server certificate as a CA to Thunderbird instead of the CA certificate

Comment: Please use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. - What do get to see when you use the "view" option in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa3px.png?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I added both .crt files that were the result of the CA creation procedure from the tutorial, but the problem is still the same. How can I tell the difference between a CA certificate and a CA server certificate?

Comment: This day and age it is not really necessary to use private CA for hostnames with public FQDN, because we have Let's Encrypt. Using public PKI removes the bother of deploying an extra CA to all the clients.

Comment: @HBruijn Thank you for your tips. I will correct it.
After clicking on "View" I have this: https://imgur.com/SkfAZIZ
Do you need to see more?

Comment: @EsaJokinen Yes, I know, but this server only works locally and for security reasons I don't want to expose it to the world and have to renew the certificate every 3 months.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. After generating the certificate this way https://resonant-cement-f3c.notion.site/Self-Signed-Certificates-Create-your-own-Certificate-Authority-CA-for-local-HTTPS-sites-536636144b124904a52e4ac68973bb2c with the appropriate name assigned DNS server and IP address here  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkEHu.png) Thunderbird doesn't show me a warning when sending messages.
Thank you for your tips.